# How can I extract value from command line output?

Tags: parsing, cmd, elixir

I have a function, which gets information of all usb connected devices.

`connected_devices = :os.cmd('usb-devices | grep -A 1 Product=')`

It gives me `'S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller\nS:  SerialNumber=0000:00:3d.0\n--\nS:  Product=HP Truevision HD\nS:  SerialNumber=201001010001\n--\nS:  Product=xHCI Host Controller\nS:  SerialNumber=0000:00:16.0\n--\nS:  Product=iPhone\nS:  SerialNumber=1d19427ba66fd77d12a836593af57c21c993f0c9\n--\nS:  Product=xHCI Host Controller\nS:  SerialNumber=0000:00:16.0\n'`

From output of above function, I want to extract value of `Product` and `SerialNumber` so I can make list of objects like `[{product: something, serial_number: some number} ...]`

How can I extract value from command line output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first split on `--` so that each chunk contains 1 product and 1 serial_number. Then use regular expressions to extract the relevant data from each chunk:

```
output = 'S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller\nS:  SerialNumber=0000:00:3d.0\n--\nS:  Product=HP Truevision HD\nS:  SerialNumber=201001010001\n--\nS:  Product=xHCI Host Controller\nS:  SerialNumber=0000:00:16.0\n--\nS:  Product=iPhone\nS:  SerialNumber=1d19427ba66fd77d12a836593af57c21c993f0c9\n--\nS:  Product=xHCI Host Controller\nS:  SerialNumber=0000:00:16.0\n'

output
|> List.to_string()
|> String.split("--")
|> Enum.map(fn chunk ->
  [_, product] = Regex.run(~r/Product=(.+)/, chunk)
  [_, serial_number] = Regex.run(~r/SerialNumber=(.+)/, chunk)
  %{product: product, serial_number: serial_number}
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
[
  %{product: "EHCI Host Controller", serial_number: "0000:00:3d.0"},
  %{product: "HP Truevision HD", serial_number: "201001010001"},
  %{product: "xHCI Host Controller", serial_number: "0000:00:16.0"},
  %{
    product: "iPhone",
    serial_number: "1d19427ba66fd77d12a836593af57c21c993f0c9"
  },
  %{product: "xHCI Host Controller", serial_number: "0000:00:16.0"}
]
```